# Solving ODE using Euler's method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function, euler-lagrange-equation

Given that x' = tx, x(0) = 1, find x(1), and use Euler’s
method with n steps to find an approximation to x(1). (You will end up
with a product of n terms whose limit (as n → ∞) is $sqrt(e)$)

I calculated x(1) using the standard way of solving the ODE by integration and managed to find $sqrt(e)$ but I'm having trouble finding this using Euler. What I did is:

Xn+1 = Xn + X'h where h=$\frac{1}{N}$

substituting the X' by tx I have

Xn+1 = Xn + tx($\frac{1}{N}$) = Xn(1+$\frac{t}{N}$)

So Xn = $(1+\frac{t}{N})^N$ and simplifying this I have Xn = $((1+\frac{1}{N})^N)^t$ and taking the limit as n → ∞ I only get $e^t$. Where did I make a mistake? I don't know where does the square root comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is more or less correct, but there are some indexing mistakes which may be leading to confusion. Consider for instance that $N$ is a *fixed* step size, whereas the update rule applies for any iteration of the algorithm. So the rule is more properly written as
$$X_{i+1} = X_i + \frac{t}{N}X_i.$$
Now, what is $t$ at iteration $i$? $\frac{i}{N}$, of course. So
$$X_{i+1} = \left(1 + \frac{i}{N^2}\right)X_i$$
and
$$X_N = \prod_{i=0}^{N-1} \left(1+\frac{i}{N^2}\right).$$

Comment: Do you mind explaining how the power of N got replaced by the summation? And how does the limit of summation leads to square root of e?

Comment: @lello what do you mean? There is no summation, just a product of binomials

Comment: Sorry I misread the notation. But how does the limit of this goes to e^(1/2)?

Comment: @Lello That's almost worth an entire new question, but here's a hint: take the logarithm, then use the fact that for $x$ small, $\log (1+x) \approx x$.